# Pull all values and keys related to data being searched or matched to

Tags: php, json

I am probably searching wrong but I havent been able to find a topic that fully helps understand how to pull all the data out of this multidimensional array from a json file. I am trying to pull all data that is related to a certain term or piece of data and return its key and value.

So far I have tried this and its somewhat works.

JSON - https://gist.github.com/Ryahn/ac8fcc8ae77e9a6ee9138e268b592ed3

```
$result = file_get_contents('21st.json');
$json = json_decode($result,true);

$term = 871957;

foreach ($json as $key => $value)
{

    if ($value = $term)
    {
        echo $value;
        echo $key;
        foreach ( $value as $key1 => $value2 )
        {
            if ($value2 = $term)
            {
                echo $value2;
                echo $key1;
                foreach ( $value2 as $key2 => $value3 )
                {
                    echo $value3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are multiple levels and parents that may be tied to one ID. I have yet to figure out how to pull all them at once.

Thank you in advance <3

Comment: Put your JSON as well.

Comment: @Noman Added a gist link. Its pretty big

Comment: Oh, you edit your question. Let me check.

Comment: `$value = $term` means you're assigning, you want `$value == $term`

Comment: Well, then thats a little embarrassing. I may have to sleep on this. I still cant for the life of me get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using [isset](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check if the user is in the users section and  [array_filter](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) plus [in_array](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to search the tag users array:

```
$result = file_get_contents('21st.json');
$json = json_decode($result,true);

$userId = 871957;
$user = isset($json['users'][$userId]) ? $json['users'][$userId] : null;

$tags = [];
if ($user) {
    $tags = array_filter($json['tags'], function($tag) use ($userId) {
        return in_array($userId, $tag['users']);
    });
}

$tagIds = array_keys($tags);
```

Comment: The only issue I have is that the json is formated with $json['tags']['tagid']['users']. The tagid is the id of the tag that is assigned to the user. I dont have a way of pulling those out at the moment.

Thank you though.

Comment: I've added an example how to extract the tag IDs from the filtered array. Try to use native functions where possible - their C implementation can sometimes be quicker than looping manually

Comment: Ah right. working on something for 12 hours does crazy things to your mind. I will definitely write something out and see what I get.

Comment: Definitely. I think on this note, I will get some sleep and then report back later on what I get and/or able to accomplish.

Comment: Enjoy! Just to point out that my solution should work verbatim, you just need to pass the variables to a templating engine (or echo/var_dump).

Answer (score 0):

Some tweaking in your code, Replaced `=` to `==`

```
$result = file_get_contents('21st.json');
$json = json_decode($result,true);

$term = 871957;

foreach ($json as $key => $value)
{

    if ($value == $term)
    {
        echo $value;
        echo $key;
        foreach ( $value as $key1 => $value2 )
        {
            if ($value2 == $term)
            {
                echo $value2;
                echo $key1;
                foreach ( $value2 as $key2 => $value3 )
                {
                    echo $value3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S** First check this if it is ok so kindly tell me.

Comment: Have you check @jedifans answer ?

Comment: @norman, yes. Trying it out and editting to see if it can work.